# How do I set the last row in a DataGridView to a different color?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have found numerous way to change the back color in a DataGridView but can't find a way to change the color of the last row (entry or add line)  below is my code for the Add Contact button.  when I change the color it changes the entire table.  I would like to change the last row only and have it selected so that the user can simply start typing to add the new contact.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
private void button_Add_Contact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customer_Ship_ContactsDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
    customer_Ship_ContactsDataGridView.ReadOnly = false;

    int rowCount = customer_Ship_ContactsDataGridView.Rows.Count;
    customer_Ship_ContactsDataGridView.CurrentCell = customer_Ship_ContactsDataGridView.Rows[rowCount - 1].Cells[0];

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in customer_Ship_ContactsDataGridView.Rows)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
```

Comment: your binding your grid to a table,so you should try adding a row to the table and that will be added to the grid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that you want last line to be filled with a color, and while editing also the color should be there, and also you want these things to be happened while data is retrieved through Dataset. You also wanted to focus upon to the last editable row while form is loaded..
.

.

Try to use the code in a seperate project file so that you can see howz it working. While doing so create empty project and just add one dataGridView1.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Shown += Form1_Shown;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView1.CellBeginEdit += dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit;
        dataGridView1.RowStateChanged += dataGridView1_RowStateChanged;
        dSet = fillDataSet();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        dSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add();
    }

    void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1];
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
    }

    DataSet fillDataSet()
    {
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
        dSet = new DataSet();
        DataTable table = new DataTable("Names");
        table.Columns.Add("ID");
        table.Columns.Add("Name");
        table.Columns.Add("Gender");
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Salim", "Male" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Salim", "Male" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Salim", "Male" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "Salim", "Male" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "Salim", "Male" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, "Salim", "Male" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, "Salim", "Male" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 8, "Salim", "Male" });
        dSet.Tables.Add(table);
        return dSet;
    }

    void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dSet.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1)dSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            String ssNair = e.StateChanged.ToString();
            if (e.Row.Index > 0)
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index - 1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

For the kind of option you need, you should set AllowUsersToAddRows property to false, and add rows depending upon some condition.

Here I'm adding a new row, while the last column of the last row is being edited.

As you're binding with a dataSet, rows cannot be added directly by dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); So rows here are being added using the DataTable.Rows.Add() method.

And also DataGridView.RowsAdded event wont work while filling up data with Dataset, So hav used the DataGridView.RowStateChanged event

Comment: If you want execute some function after all controls loaded(set focus for example) set focus in handler of `Shown` event without timers

Comment: thanks for expanding this out.  I actually understood how this is all working it just has some things that I don't want like...you can edit any or all rows, when you start typing in the last column a new row is added.  this has been very helpful however and thanks for taking the time. it has given me a better understanding of DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a For loop instead of a foreach;

```
int counter = customer_Ship_ContactsDataGridView.Rows.count;

for(int i = 0; i< counter; i++){
if(i == counter){
//this is where your LAST LINE code goes
  row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
} else {
//this is your normal code NOT LAST LINE
  row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
}
```

so basically your for loop will iterate 1 time per each row you have . on the last iteration it will do the alternate code.

worth noting: rows.count  might actually be rows.length  or some other wording to get the amount of rows into that variable, i am merely trying to draw your attention to the for loop as a solution.

Re-edit:  The above example makes all of the rows yellows and the last row red

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and working one
..
Create a RowsAdded Event

```
public Form1()
    {
        dataGridView1.RowsAdded += dataGridView1_RowsAdded;
    }

void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > 0)
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex - 1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
```

Comment: this is making the line with the * turn yellow which is the direction I am trying to go.  as soon as I start to type in the row another row is now added and the yellow row is the next line with the * which ok because I am getting closer to what I am after.

Comment: how would i add the row to the dataset first then i can color the row yellow and put focus in the first column.  thanks for your help its is moving in the right direction